Using std::normal_distribution in function template
I'm working on a function that generates a uniformly random point on the surface of unit d dimensional hypersphere. What I'm trying to do is to generate d random numbers with standard normal distribution to form a d dimensional vector, and then simply normalize it (Why? See here to find out: Hypersphere point picking). Here is my C++ code
#include <iostream>
#include <random> 
#include <vector>

std::random_device         _random_device;
std::mt19937               generate(_random_device());
std::normal_distribution<> standard_normal(0, 1);

template <typename type> 
std::vector<type> uniform_on_unit_sphere (const int &d) {
    std::vector<type> v(d); 
    type v_2norm_sq = 0;   
    type v_2norm_inv; 
    type rand; 

    for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
        rand        = standard_normal(generate); 
        v[k]        = rand;
        v_2norm_sq += rand * rand;  
    }

    v_2norm_inv = 1.0 / std::sqrt(v_2norm_sq); 

    for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {v[k] *= v_2norm_inv;}

    return v;
}

int main() {

    int d = 5; 
    std::vector<double> u = uniform_on_unit_sphere(d); 

    for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
        std::cout << u[k] << " "; 
    }
    
    return 0; 
}

When I run the code, it gives an error
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:45:53: error: no matching function for call to 'uniform_on_unit_sphere(int&)'
   45 |     std::vector<double> u = uniform_on_unit_sphere(d);
      |                                                     ^
main.cpp:23:19: note: candidate: 'template<class type> std::vector<_RealType> uniform_on_unit_sphere(const int&)'  
   23 | std::vector<type> uniform_on_unit_sphere (const int &d) {
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:23:19: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:45:53: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'type'
   45 |     std::vector<double> u = uniform_on_unit_sphere(d);
      | 

I want to make use of template to define uniform_on_unit_sphere() that can use for all real number data types. How should I fix?

Try std::vector<double> u = uniform_on_unit_sphere<double>(d); as template parameters cannot be deduced from the function return type.

See Function Template argument deduction.

@RichardCritten The question is not about the argument deduction.

Side note: You can save yourself from having a global variable hanging around forever and never being used again: Delete the std::random_device _random_device; line and change generate(_random_device()); to generate(std::random_device{}());. Breakdown: std::random_device{} Creates a temporary random_device, std::random_device{}() gets a random number from the temporary. and the rest proceeds as you currently have it except the temporary random_device goes out of scope and is destroyed at the end of the line. Since you never use it again, good riddance.
